# Doubt regarding the proof of $\Sigma[\sigma^{p},\sigma^{p-1}][\sigma^{p-1},\sigma^{p-2}]=0$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Incidence number is defined as follows:

> $K$ be a complex with $\sigma^p,\sigma^{p+1}\in K$. To each such pair we associate an incidence number $[\sigma^{p+1},\sigma^p]$ as:
>
> 1. If $\sigma^p$ is not a face of $\sigma^{p+1}$ then it is 0
> 2. If it is, then let $+\sigma^{p}=\langle a_0...a_p\rangle$ and $\sigma^{p+1}=\pm\langle va_0...a_p\rangle$ where $v$ is a vertex of $\sigma^{p+1}$ not in $\sigma^{p}$. If $\sigma^{p+1}=+\langle va_0...a_p\rangle$ then it is $1$, if $\sigma^{p+1}=-\langle va_0...a_p\rangle$ then it is $-1$

Now the theorem states:

> Let $K$ be a complex and $\sigma^{p}$ be a simplex in $K$ with a $(p-2)$-face $\sigma^{p-2}$, then $\Sigma[\sigma^{p},\sigma^{p-1}][\sigma^{p-1},\sigma^{p-2}]=0$

The proof goes like this:

> Let $+\sigma^{p-2}=\langle v_0...v_{p-2} \rangle$ and $a,b$ be the two additional vertices in $\sigma^{p}$, $+\sigma^{p}=\langle abv_0...v_{p-2} \rangle$, let $\sigma^{p-1}_1=\langle av_0...v_{p-2} \rangle$ and $\sigma^{p-1}_2=\langle bv_0...v_{p-2} \rangle$. Now there are 4 cases:

> Case 1. $+\sigma^{p-1}_1=+\langle av_0...v_{p-2} \rangle$ and $+\sigma^{p-1}_2=+\langle bv_0...v_{p-2} \rangle$

Here the book states that:

> $[\sigma^{p},\sigma^{p-1}_1]=-1, [\sigma^{p-1}_1,\sigma^{p-2}]=+1, [\sigma^{p},\sigma^{p-1}_2]=+1,
> [\sigma^{p-1}_2,\sigma^{p-2}]=+1$

But I don't understand how they are $+1$. The ordering of $\sigma^{p-1}_1$ is from $a<v_0<...<v_{p-2}$ and we're going from $a$ to $v_{p-2}$ then again from $v_0$ to $v_{p-2}$ in case of $\sigma^{p-2}$ by changing the direction, so shouldn't it be $-1$?

How are these being calculated? I cannot see how it follows from the definition the book has given.

Thanks.

Comment: Let $+\tau=\langle w_0, w_1,\cdots, w_k\rangle$, then $\left\langle w_{f(0)}, w_{f(1)},\cdots ,w_{f(k)}\right\rangle=+\tau$ if and only if $f\colon \{0,1,...,k\}\to \{0,1,...,k\}$ is an even permutation. Thus when $f$ is a transposition, then $\left\langle w_{f(0)}, w_{f(1)},\cdots ,w_{f(k)}\right\rangle=-\tau$.